# Nested Models Error in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

I have two models App and Contact. App has a has_one relationship with Contact. I have declared the accepts_nested_attributes_for clause in the App model for Contact. Now, in the apps_controller, if I use the build method on the app object, I get an error for the the nil class, even though I had declared the relationship.

**App.rb**

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact_person, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_person
end
```

**ContactPerson.rb**

```
class ContactPerson < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
end
```

**apps_controller.rb**

```
def new
  @app = App.new
  @app.contact_person.build
end
```

Could you please point me out whether am I doing anything incorrectly. I have used nested models before but have not encountered this error.

Answer (score 3):

I am supposed to use `@app.build_contact_person` instead of `@app.contact_person.build`. In this way, it worked :)

Comment: Hmm very strange for me.. @app.contact_person.build should have worked !! I have used it in similar way and it worked for me !

Answer (score 0):

Declaring association does not automatically creates it:

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :contact_person, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :contact_person
  # Adding this line should work
  after_create { self.contact_person = ContactPerson.new }
end
```

Comment: hey thanks for the answer.yes i added your suggestion but still it is not working. I am still getting undefined method `build' for nil:NilClass when trying to view the apps/new page.

Comment: @Felix if you're using the `after_create` observer Dmytrii suggested you can remove the `@app.contact_person.build` line from the controller.

Comment: @Felix, showing more information would help; including the view and call stack.